# Single column form layout for mobile, double column for desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a form that has a two column layout.  In each column I have a label with the input text element directly under the label.

When I view on mobile, it is responsive, but it just makes the input boxes smaller, and stays on two columns. What I want it to do is to switch to a single column layout.  Label, with input element underneath, then next label under that and so on.

I am able to display two different forms based on screen size with media css settings, but then I have two copies of same form.  I'm trying to avoid maintaining two separate copies.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some sample HTML of your page, very likely you just need to add the extra div classes such as

`<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12"> </div>`

which would display the div as 2 column when on a medium device and a 12 column when on a small display device.

Check the link try resizing the window down and you see the div jump to filling the page instead.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKwoVa

Comment: that led me in the right direction.  I needed to do col-xs-12 and that forced the next field to the next row.  Thanks!